# What's the easiest and safest circuit to detect power outage?

Tags: transistors, power, relay, zigbee

I have a battery powered Zigbee water leakage sensor that basically when 2 pins short circuit (water passes between them) it sends me a message. I want to make it such that when the power goes down, it short circuits and I get a message.

What is the easiest circuit that I can safely build and plug into a power outlet and connect to the sensor's 2 pins?

I thought about a relay that is triggered by a transistor and the base of the transistor goes around a power cable which is always on, so when energy goes down the transistor base goes off and it switches the relay. I believe the eletromagnetism of the cable will trigger the transistor

Is there something even better? Safer? No fire risks

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a 120 V (or 240 V,depending on your line voltage) relay with the coil connected to mains, and the Normally Open relay contacts connected to your alarm device.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a reasonable quality wall-wart (you may have one lying around from some defunct or obsolete piece of equipment - now might be the time it comes in useful). Or a new USB-output adapter ('charger') which will supply 5VDC.

That will provide a safe, short-circuit protected (usually) galvanically isolated low voltage power source.

Then pick a DC signal relay with a normally closed contact and wire that contact across the pins you want to short when the power goes off.

Something like a Panasonic [TX2-5V](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/cdn/e/control/relay/signal/catalog/mech_eng_tx.pdf)  (match the coil voltage to the power source - so it might not be 5V) would be an appropriate relay for a quite reasonable price.